# спрайты в phaser.js

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, phaser-framework

Не могу добавить спрайт, который находится в папке вместе с js, с http-адресом проблем нет. Где находится js есть папки и вот так выглядит путь assets/images. В прелоадере - this.load.image('freeman', 'assets/images/freeman'), в create - this.add.sprite(200, 200, 'freeman'). Адрес верный, вместо спрайта черный прямоугольник, готовлю проект, гуглил - решил спросить здесь!

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил -  картинки должны быть в одной директории с index.html.